# GroupBy and IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I was going through the GroupBy method in LINQ :

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> GroupBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer
)
```

I understand how to use GroupBy and what it returns. I want to understand the significance of `IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer` and what is it actually used for in GroupBy.

Comment: `return x.Length - y.Length >= 0;` Why are you using this as a way to measure equality?

Comment: I just wanted to run it to see how it works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` object will be used to perform a two-step check to see if a `TKey` instance is "equal" to the key of an existing group and thus should be in that group:

1. It checks the hash code of the item (using `GetHashCode`) against the hash code of existing keys.  If it does not equal any of those values it is added to a new group
2. If a matching hash code is found, it *then* checks for equality (using `Equals`).  If the item is "equal to" the group key, the item is added to that group.

If you do *not* supply a comparer (either by passing `null` or using one of the overloads that does not have that parameter), the "default" comparer is used, which uses the `TKey` class itself if it implements `IEquatable` or any applicable overrides of `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

So this implies a few key relationships between `Equals` and `GetHashCode`:

- If two items are equal, they *must* have the same hash code.
- The opposite is not true - two items that have the same hash code do not *have* to be equal.

Comment: Nicely explained. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've provided a nonsensical equality comparer, so your results are going to be nonsensical.  Your hash code is based on the reference to the comparer itself, which has nothing to do with anything in your `Equals` method, and in your `Equals` method you're saying that two objects are equal if the first object is as long or longer than the second string.  This just makes no sense, it even violates basic properties of equality in that the order of the parameters should be irrelevant.

Comment: I am not sure how to use it, so I wrote it like that for quick result to see how it would work

Comment: @VishalAnand You can read the documentation to see how it works.  When you use it incorrectly, it doesn't do anything sensible, as you've seen for yourself.  If you have no idea what you actually want to do, there's no way for us to help you do it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have edited the question. Maybe now it will make more sense. You are right, maybe the implementation made no sense. I am just playing around the API. Like when we use OrderBy or OrderByDescending or ThenBy, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer, is used to compare for ordering. I am not able to understand the scenarios where I would do such a thing in GroupBy. Why do I need to compare in group by. If you can explain with an example that will help me.

Comment: @VishalAnand Read the documentation to see why it's there and how it's used.  It explains all of that.