# Breakpoint in GetHashCode of IEqualityComparer + GroupBy not hit

Tags: c#, linq, iequalitycomparer

Code example:

```
 var positions = new List<Position>();

 for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
 {
     positions.Add(new Position { Code = "A", Value = i });
     positions.Add(new Position { Code = "A", Value = i });
 }
 var test = positions.GroupBy(p => p, new PositionComparer());

public class Position
{
    public string Code;
    public int Value;
}
public class PositionComparer : IEqualityComparer<Position>
{
    public bool Equals(Position x, Position y)
    {
        return x.Code == y.Code && x.Value == y.Value;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(Position pos)
    {
        unchecked
        {
           int hash = 17;
           hash = hash * 31 + pos.Code.GetHashCode();
           hash = hash * 31 + pos.Value;
           return hash;
         }
     }
 }
```

I have a breakpoint in `GetHashCode` (and in `Equals`).
The breakpoint is not hit during the `GroupBy`, why not?

Comment: Do you do anything with `test` once you've set it? This is possibly deferred execution preventing the breakpoints being hit as the code hasn't actually run.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355018/groupby-and-iequalitycomparertkey-comparer

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about deferred execution ...
After e.g. a `foreach` the breakpoint is hit ...

Comment: No worries, I've thrown an answer in as that was the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for `GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534334(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For Each in Visual Basic.

Unless you actually do something with `test` in your code the grouping won't actually be executed and therefore your `PositionComparer` won't get executed either.

Comment: It is the same as with the Results View in the Watch window in Debug mode. Only when you unfold it, "Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable".

Comment: @Gerard I think that when you expand Results View, the breakpoint isn't reached, it is only reached if you pass a collection though a foreach (ex.)... Anyone know if is it a compiler specifc behavior?