# Linq Group By - Unable to group on custom classes?

Tags: linq, group-by

I have noticed that when I do a LINQ - group by, it only seems to be working if I dont group on any of my custom classes.

I have a Product class (shown below) and I would like to group on Product.Id ,Product.Variant (object) and on Product.Options (ICollection) (because my source list contains multiple times the same Product but with different Variants and / or Options)

Product:

```
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Variant Variant { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Option> Options{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

The code below will do a grouping, but only on my Product.ID, when I try to also group on Variant / Options, I get no grouping (well, not the grouping I am intending to make)  as it will return just as much items as my source list.

```
        IEnumerable<productAndSum> productsAndSums = unmappedProducts
            .GroupBy(prod => new { Id = prod.Id}) 
            .Select(group => new productAndSum()
            {
                Key = group.Key,
                Sum = group.Sum(x => x.Amount)
            });
```

If I am on the right track and the issue is related to the Objects, then it might be usefull to add that also Option and Variant have multiple objects and collections themselves, or is this too deep?

Extra information: I first started to just group by my Product class (not Id, Variant & Options separately), but this was unsuccessful. so I started eliminating properties and this is how I found out this issue. I think that solving this issue will result in killing two birds with one stone.

Warm regards

Comment: Better to know original idea. I don't think group by is right operator in your case.

Comment: You have to tell C# when two `Variant`s are equal and when two `Options` collections are equal. By default, two class instances are never equal. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32355018/861716. This isn't trivial, and it probably doesn't make much sense seeing your remark *Option and Variant have multiple objects and collections themselves*. As said: what's the idea? Or: you're asking about problem B, but what is the preceding problem A?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I went trough the link you have provided me, but I will still explain the the original idea: I want to find out how many times a Product is found in this list, and sum up the Amount for that Product (think of it as something like Sales) my source list is the result of another function that reads from multiple CSV files, I am trying to find out the Sum of the amount for each Product (this is why I chose group by, and then proceed to call Sum on Amount) a variant can be a specific type of Tea (always or null) and Option is like adding sugar to the Tea (not always)

Comment: You can group on multiple properties. You can group on Product Id and Variant by just changing your GroupBy statement like so `GroupBy(prod => { Id = prod.Id, Variant = prod.Variant })`. However, your additional requirement to also group by different collections of options is a little trickier. Maybe add a delimited string to the GroupBy anonymous object. i.e. `GroupBy(prod => { Id = prod.Id, Variant = prod.Variant , Options = string.Join(", ", prod.Options.Select(o => o.Name)})`.